# How does using + as a casting mechanism work?

Tags: javascript, string, casting, type-conversion, typeof

I have seen code where strings were casted to numbers using the plus operator.

This would look something like:

```
var x ="5",y;
y = +x;
console.log(typeof y) //number
```

How does this work?

Comment: @Sebas The JavaScript engine is not guessing what you want, it's just applying the operator. And it's not making one literal as with `-4`, it's just, dynamically, applying the operator to what follows.

Comment: @dystroy, I understand. In my opinion though, implicitely making the convertion is already guessing that it is what you, the coder, wanted. Other strongly typed languages would crash. That's the same as saying that affecting a string value to a variable, javascript guesses the type. It is correct since this is the only way the engine has to know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there are two `+` operators : the binary + operator and this one : the **Unary + operator**.

See how it's described [in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) :

> - (Unary Plus)
>
> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and **evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to converts it into a number**, if it isn't
>   already. For example, y = +x takes the value of x and assigns that to
>   y; that is, if x were 3, y would get the value 3 and x would retain
>   the value 3; but if x were the string "3", y would also get the value
>   3. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a
>   number, because it does not perform any other operations on the
>   number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats,
>   as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in
>   both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
>   Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
>   parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

Comment: Is this valid for all browsers? just curious

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "5",
    y;
```

You're declaring two variables named respectively `x` and `y`. The former is set to hold the string `"5"`, the latter holds the `undefined` value(since it's declared but not defined).
Then you're setting `y` to be the conversion in `Number` type of the string `"5"`(via the unary operator `+`), which is `5`. So you're getting `typeof y` to be `number`.

The `+` operator is the [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29). It evaluates an object trying to convert it into a number.